# How to install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on new laptop with 1 TB ssd drive

Tags: partitioning, ssd, btrfs

I will be getting a new laptop and would like to install Ubuntu using the btrfs file system. No encryption required.

I am looking for as much advice, suggestions, procedures others have used as well as problems encountered (such as on an ssd drive) and if clearing out old snapshots would be a routine maintenance requirement.

I am in "intermediate" linux user on desktop and servers, the command line not being an issue.

Thanking everyone ahead of time!

Comment: The answer to all if not most of the questions you pose is an opinion which makes it off topic on this site.

Comment: Installing btrfs is a valid option on Ubuntu. See this thread on Ubuntu forums - https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2484121

Comment: Just use USB stick and select btrfs from options during install. If you really prefer "safety" against speed go with btrfs then. IMHO: btrfs is not needed to use by an average user.

Comment: From my experience, btrfs adds extra complexity that requires you to research extensively in order to use its cool and unique features, like snapshots. Also, it was occasionally a bit buggy for me, several years ago. Go investigate it in detail and form your own opinion. If that research is too much to do on your own, or you don't want to bother with it all, then btrfs is probably not the right choice of filesystem for you.